# Access Application before onCreate() is called during androidTest

Tags: java, android, junit, android-testing, android-instrumentation

`MyApplication` class (extends `Application`), when it starts up, will launch a service to check a `SharedPreference` value. If the value is `false`, then some data gets initialized.

For testing purposes, I would like to modify this `SharedPreference` to be `true` so the data initialization does not happen. However when I do this, a race condition happens and the `MyApplication.onCreate()` is called before I have a chance to modify the preference.

How can I modify the preference before `MyApplication.onCreate()` is called? Is something like this even possible?

**MyApplication.java**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public static AppComponent component;

    public MyApplication() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        injectDependencies();

        super.onCreate();
        initializeDatabase();
    }

    private void injectDependencies() {
        if (component == null)
            component = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                    .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                    .build();

        component.inject(this);
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    public static void setComponent(AppComponent component) {
        MyApplication.component = component;
    }

    private void initializeDatabase() {
        Intent intent = DataInitializationService.createIntent(this, null);
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

**SearchFragmentTest.java**  (in src/androidTest flavor)

```
public class SearchScreenFragmentTest {
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
            SearchActivity.class,
            true,    // initialTouchMode
            false);  // launchActivity. False to set intent per method

    public SearchScreenFragmentTest() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        //gets run AFTER `MyApplication.onCreate()`. I want this to be called BEFORE.
        new TestUtils.TestDataInitter(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext())
                .clearPrefs(true)
                .acceptIntro(true)
                .initDatabaseFake(true)
                .init();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        new TestUtils.TestDataInitter(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext())
                .clearPrefs(true)
                .acceptIntro(true)
                .initDatabaseFake(false)
                .init();
    }

}
```

Comment: You can create a test version of your `MyApplication` by extending it and overriding `onCreate`. Do your preference change and after that call `super.onCreate`. Use this `MyTestApplication` during instrumentation tests.

Comment: I was hoping to override that behavior from the point of view of an instrumentation test